# Flutter Inherited Custom AppBar disappear on TextField tap

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I'm using a custom appBar and a bottomNavigationBar in a Scaffold, per below code:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: LogoAppBar(),
      drawer: topDrawer(),
      body: _pageOptions[_selectedTab],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(...)
```

When I navigate via the BottomNavigationBar the custom AppBar sticks at the top of the new screen, just like I want it to.

However, when I navigate and thereafter tap on a TextField on the new screen to enter some text, the inherited AppBar automatically disappear (when the keyboard shows up).

The full code for this screen is rather long and therefore rather impractical to post here, but it basically boils down to the following:

```
return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
     body: Column(
       children: [
       Container(
         Column(
          children: [
            DropDownButton(...),
            TextField(...), // with a textSearchController
          ],
       Expanded(
          child: ListViewBuilder(...) // showing a list based on the search
```

Is there any way to make the AppBar from the inherited class stick without putting a new appBar in the Scaffold in the class I navigated to?

Comment: Please share your code. I believe you are using custom appBar inside SingleChildScrollView or any other scrollable widget.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ujjwal! I edited the post to show an overview of the code. I hope it's enough to see what's going on? I'm not using the appBar inside SingleChildScrollView, but am using the ListViewBuilder (on the second screen). Please let me know if you want to see any other details of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ujjwal's suggestion was incredibly helpful. I removed the Scaffold and unfortunately the problem persisted, but it made me realize that I had also wrapped the LogoAppBar() code in a Scaffold. Once I removed the Scaffold from the LogoAppBar() it all worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Scaffold as you are already calling it once in the main screen.

```
return Column(
       children: [
       Container(
         Column(
          children: [
            DropDownButton(...),
            TextField(...), // with a textSearchController
          ],
       Expanded(
          child: ListViewBuilder(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal! I did as suggested and the problem persisted. But your guidance lead me to review the code in the LogoAppBar() again. Thanks to your suggestion I realized that I had also wrapped the code in that widget in a Scaffold. I removed it and it now works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it helped, I would appreciate if you can give my answer a tick

Comment: I've marked your answer as useful. As I'm a rather new stackoverflow user my my votes are unfortunately not displayed on the website yet as I haven't reach a reputation of 15. But I hope my votes already count on your profile? Thanks again for your help!